# Ckeditor disallow img element

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg

I am using ckeditor.
I checked which elements were disallowed by default by running:

```
ckEditor.on( 'instanceReady', function() {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(ckEditor.filter.allowedContent, null, '\t'));    
    });
```

This shows that the `img` element is allowed (despite the fact that the img button does not appear in my toolbar).

Since I don't wish for users to be able to submit code with the `img` element, I wanted to disallow this altogether. I tried disallowing it in the `config.js` file with:

```
config.disallowedContent = 'img';
```

and also tried when initializing the editor:

```
CKEDITOR.replace("comment", {
        disallowedContent: 'img'
    });
```

When I display the allowed content with the `ckEditor.filter.allowedContent` command, the `img` element is still shown as allowed.

What am I doing wrong? I figure it's still necessary to disallow `img` for cases where someone pastes code in the editor...

(I'm also validating server side but would ideally like for server side and client side to match, ie: for both to disallow `img`).

Thanks

Comment: It works if you pass the config to the replace function: https://jsfiddle.net/reoh7j74/214/ The documentation states that the best way would be to define it in page: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_configuration

Comment: You maybe need a different version of ckeditor, content filter was introduced in 4.1: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter

Comment: Hey, thanks, I'm running version 4.7.3. When I run your fiddle and look at what is allowed: https://jsfiddle.net/bfyuL1cy/, it appears the `img` tag is still there. I don't really understand your code either. Why wouldn't it suffice to just pass `disallowedContent: 'img'` into the replace function (without the `disablePlugin...` code)?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It seems only disallowedcontent is enough https://jsfiddle.net/reoh7j74/216/ . Passing the config in the replace function should have highest priority so not sure why it doesn't work in your project.

Comment: This indeed removes the image button. But it does not remove the ability to include an `img` tag/element in the html. When you check which content is allowed via html, the `img` tag still comes up as allowed. Do you understand what I mean? I want the `img` tag to be forbidden altogether. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Have you by any chance set `allowedContent` to `true`?

Comment: In the last fiddle I posted I'm not able to paste an image in the content nor will an image tag in the source stay there when switching wysiwyg editing mode.

Comment: @HMR ah, ok, I see what you mean. When you try to add an img tag via th html editor it indeed restricts it. However, look here: https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_allowed_content_rules (under "debugging" section) and see that they say to check what is "allowed" by running the `ckeditor.filter.allowedContent` line. This is a fiddle of it: https://jsfiddle.net/xykjcp6o/. Have a look at the console and you'll see that the `img` tag is still allowed.

Comment: Perhaps `ckeditor.filter.allowedContent` lists the contents of `allowedContent` specifically and does not remove any element that is actually not allowed because of `disallowedContent`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to disallow images please use below code:

```
CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
   disallowedContent: 'img'
});
```

Please note that `CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.filter.disallowedContent` and 
`CKEDITOR.instances.editor1.filter.allowedContent` are two separate lists and adding element to one doesn't remove it from other. You define (or editor does that by default) list of allowed elements in [allowedContent list](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent) and list of disallowed elements in [disallowedContent list](https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-disallowedContent). The later has higher priority than the former one - https://docs.ckeditor.com/ckeditor4/docs/#!/guide/dev_disallowed_content. This is why images won’t be allowed in the editor.